# Use Benthic Golden "ImpExp 6" from python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Benthic Golden6 "ImpExp6" tool -- I can successfully import 122+K rows of data from csv file.

Attempting to automate via `.py` as I have with other smaller data sets and I am encountering the exceeded table space error. I dropped everything from the user, maximizing available space just for test purposes-- continue to receive the error -- however I can use the import tool and import the 122K rows no problems.

If I can import the file manually with no issues -- should I not be able to also do so via python script? Below is the script I am using.

Note: if I use `lines = [] for lines in reader: lines.append(line)` it will append 5556 rows of data VS the nothing I am getting with the script below. Using Python2.7

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('myinfo')
cursor = connection.cursor()

L=[]
reader = csv.reader(open("myfile.csv","r"))
for row in reader:
    L.append(row)
    cursor.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY'")
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO BI_VANTAGE_TEST VALUES(:25,:24,:23,:22,:21,:20,:19,:18,:17,:16,:15,:14,:13,:12,:11,:10,:9,:8,:7,:6,:5,:4,:3,:2,:1)",L)
connection.commit
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to automate this import using an alternate method (note keystroke commands are unique to what steps I needed to complete within the tool I was utilizing).

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import pyautogui
app = Application().start("C:\myprogram.exe")
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter', 'right', 'tab'])
pyautogui.typewrite('myfile.txt')
pyautogui.typewrite(['tab'])
pyautogui.typewrite('myoracletbl')
pyautogui.typewrite(['tab', 'tab', 'tab'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
time.sleep(#seconds)
Application.Kill_(app)
```